# Use Parallel.ForEach with XmlNodeList in C#

Tags: c#, xml, parallel.foreach

I already done basic`foreach` loop with `XmlNodeList` as given bellow.

[Sample XML File (books.xml)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762271(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("books.xml");
XmlNodeList xnList = doc.SelectNodes("catalog/book");
foreach (XmlNode node in xnList)
{
   Console.WriteLine(node["author"].InnerText);
}
```

How do I convert this loop into `Parallel.ForEach` ?

I've try with this code.But it's didn't work.

```
Parallel.ForEach(xnList, (XmlNode node) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine(node["author"].InnerText);
});
```

It's says Error 2

> Argument 1: cannot convert from `System.Xml.XmlNodeList` to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.XmlNode>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`XmlNodeList` implements the non-generic `IEnumerable`. You'll need to cast it first in order to work with an `IEnumerable<XmlNode>`, as that is what `Parallel.ForEach` operates on:

```
Parallel.ForEach(xnList.Cast<XmlNode>(), (XmlNode node) =>
{
   Console.WriteLine(node["author"].InnerText);
});
```

Comment: @devopsEMK Because `Parallel.ForEach` works with an `IEnumerable<T>`, not an `IEnumerable`.

Answer (score 1):

Another tip, you can set how many parallel processes you want:

```
 Parallel.ForEach(nodes.Cast<XmlNode>(), new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 
 Environment.ProcessorCount },
 (XmlNode node) =>
 { 
      string value = node.InnerText;
      //Some other task
 });
```

In above Envorinment.ProcessorCount refers to the number of logical cores the CPU reports to Windows.  I strongly suggest keeping below this number.  I have i9 28-cores, and set to 28, pretty much locks up your machine (just leave 1-2 free).

Another use for this is that when you are debugging, it is hard to track the multi-threads breaking at the same location when you have many threads running.  Setting this to 1 will make it work like a regular Loop.

Be mindful of impacts of this.  If you are interacting with public items, remember you will have 20+ parallels calls in one hit. I have found that trying to add unique Dictionary terms for some bizarre reason tells me there are duplicates when running multithread.. works fine with just 1.